# Homeomorphic mapping of finite integer sequences to rational numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers, rational-numbers

Euclidean division method is one example of mapping finite sequences $s^K_i$ of natural integers to rational numbers $x_s$, satisfying, if my understanding is correct, a condition of uniqueness both ways.

Here, there's a variation of the problem in a multi-dimensional space. Suppose there are N finite sequences of non-negative integers of the same length l, with only one non-zero element at each position $k \le l$: if $s^n_k > 0$ then $s^j_k = 0 \; \forall \; 1 \le j \le N, j \ne n$.

Is a method known of mapping of such sequences to N-dimensional rational numbers, also with the condition of uniqueness of mapping both ways?

Comment: If you can enumerate both sets, then you have bijection; It's not very hard here, when you already have bijection between rationals and finite integer sequences. But I doubt that there is some nice bijection defined using only continued fractions and such, since you essentially have pair of sequences of the same length: one of natural numbers, and the other of numbers $1, \ldots N$. You could map it canonically to some subset of $\mathbb Q \times \{1, \ldots N\}^*$, where $*$ denotes finite sequences.